# Webpack configuration error reactjs

Tags: webpack

```
var path = require("path");
var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",`enter code here
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

these is my webpack.config.js file , when i am running npm start i am receiving error as :

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'

Answer (score 0):

In webpack 4 loaders does not exist anymore. It is replaced by [rules](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/).

```
var path = require("path");
var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",`enter code here
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

See there, `loaders` become `rules`

Comment: thank you, It resolved my problem , But when i try to run reactjs app with webpack , I is throwing error as npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build: `webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build script.

Comment: wich error ? Do not hesitate to accept the answer if it solved your problem.